# GAE without billing

Tags: google-app-engine

I remember years ago I deployed a simple python app on GAE without the need to enable billing. Is it still possible? All the guides and tutorials I find tell to enable billing, and I'd like not to do that.

Comment: Somewhere in the beginning of 2019 Google decided they only enable your GAE account when you add credit card information. Even when you only use the free parts/quota. They just gather that information because for them it's really interesting to have a database full of credit card info. All under the guise of preventing spam.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you have to enable billing account in order to deploy an app on GAE.

> To deploy your apps, you must enable billing. Your account will not be charged if you stay within your free quota. If your application needs resources that exceed the free quota, you will be charged for the additional usage.

So, if you don't exceed the free [quota](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) limits you won't be charged.  I think the main reason is that it won't be cool your application shutdowns just because you exceeded the limits even if you're testing.